# im making a discord bot but it says i have an incorrect token

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

so when i try to run it it says
(node:30096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.

this is the code

````
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'the token but i won't show';

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('This bot is online!');
})

bot.login('token');```
````

Answer (score 2):

`bot.login('token');` doesn't do what you think it does. Since you've encapsulated the word `token` in quotes (`''`), you've passed the *literal* string `token` as a parameter to the `login()` method.

Remove the quotes so that the contents of your variable `token` are passed, instead:

```
bot.login(token);
```

A bit more bluntly, you really should also consider brushing up on your basic JavaScript syntax.

Comment: thank you so much i just watched a video on how to do it so idrk know much sorry